# There is some way to save some variables in other file .py and import it back, in a non fix name file?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I tried a lot of ways to make a simple app before something bigger, I managed a way to save some variables in another .py file, that will be use by the user, so he chose the name of this .py file, but i want some way to get the varibles back, to show they in GUI, but import command don't accept a variable:

get_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Python file",".py")]) #gets the file name

import get_name # doesn't work

Is possible to add a non fix name to import function?

Comment: Yes, `importlib.import_module()` can do this.  That doesn't mean it's a good idea.  Remember that Python won't re-import a module it has already imported.

Comment: I suggest using something like the [tag:pickle] module for saving variables, instead of writing them to a Python file. It's more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a user needs to know anything about the code of your script (like the name of a variable, or a source file), you're making a big mistake. Instead of having your user enter the name of some file to run, you can create a dictionary that links specific commands or names to specific functions.

For example, with this `main.py`:

```
import my_functions


commands = {
  '1': my_functions.one,
  '2': my_functions.two
}


command = ''
while command != 'stop':
    command = input(f'Pick a command {list(commands.keys())} or \'stop\': ')
    if command in commands:
        commands[command]()
```

And a another file `my_functions.py`:

```
def one():
    print('Command one is running')


def two():
    print('Command two is running')
```

User interaction might look like this:

```
Pick a command (['1', '2']) or stop: 1
Command one is running
Pick a command (['1', '2']) or stop: 2
Command two is running
Pick a command (['1', '2']) or stop: stop
```

Note that functions `one()` and `two()` could have been named anything, and can change names in later versions, or live somewhere else, and what your user has to select doesn't change. That only depends on the values defined in the dictionary.

Comment: I expressed myself bad, in the app you save as in a .py file, where the data of the changes will be saved in variables, to when he open back this file in the program he gets all he have done back, in the correct places, but the problem is he can save with any name the file with the data. Tomorow i will try more, using the pickle module.